# How to get maximum value from an array of objects to use in d3.scale.linear().domain()

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an external csv file with data in columns like so:

```
name, field_goal_attempts, field_goal_makes
```

I am trying to use a linear scale but am encountering difficulty getting the maximum value for my domain.

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain(0, d3.max(...
```

I am confused as to:

1) Whether I should put the yScale function outside or inside the

```
d3.csv("filename.csv", function(data) {
```

callback function; and

2) How to get the maximum value of items in the field_goal_attempts column to then feed into the yScale function.

Here is my code at present:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 4000]) //d3.max(data, function(d) {return d })])
    .range([0, 500]);

d3.csv("test.csv", function (data) {
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("x", magic_number) // I'm not concerned about the magic numbers at this point :)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", another_magic_number)
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return d.field_goal_attempts
        })
        .attr("id", function (d, i) {
            return i
        });
});
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The data in your csv file will be in the callback you pass to the csv function (in your case the "data" parameter). So you can define yScale outside of the csv function, but if you want the max to be data dependent you will need to set it inside the callback.

As for finding the max, many D3 functions that work on arrays will accept optional accessor functions for precisely your scenario. So computing the max I would use:

```
var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.field_goal_attempts;} );
```

So you could put it all together one of two ways:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(0,100);
d3.csv("test.csv", function(data){
    var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.field_goal_attempts;} );
    yScale.domain([0,max]);
    ...
}
```

or

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(data){
    var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.field_goal_attempts;} );
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,max]);
    ...
}
```

If you want to find both max and min then I suggest using d3.extent(...) which should also accept an accessor function and will return an array of length 2 with the min and max values.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is my first question and am grateful for the help and the friendly manner in which it was delivered. I accepted your answer over Christopher Chiche's because it felt "more d3" by not not requiring a loop. I implemented your second solution but had to make two alterations to get it to work, namely using '+' in front of d.field_goal_attempts so that max returned 2000 and not 600, and to enclose values in domain() in square brackets. I'm new so I don't want to change your code in case I'm wrong, but thought it'd be good to tell you :). Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you will need the '+' in front of field_goal_attempts if the value is stored as a string. And you are absolutely right about the argument to domain being an array! I will make the edits. Glad I could help!

Comment: Wow not adding that + at the beginning was giving me so many problems, you are a life saver @Superboggly!

Comment: This answer was incredibly helpful to me as a d3 newbie. I was having the same difficulty working out the max value of nested data.

Answer (score 2):

1) The yScale can stay outside of the `d3.csv()` function as long as you update the domain inside of the function when having computed the max. For example you could do the following inside of `d3.csv()`:

```
yScale.domain([0, my_max])
```

2) To compute the max, here is the method I usually use:

```
//Create list containing only field_goal_attempts
field_goal_attempts_list = data.forEach(function(d){return d.field_goal_attempts})

//Compute max using d3.max() function
field_goal_attempts_max = d3.max(field_goal_attempts_list)
```

It is true that passing such function to `d3.max()` would be great but as far as I know it is not. The advantage of first computing the list and then computing the max is that you do less computation if you want to compute the min, the mean or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is my first question and am grateful for the help and the friendly manner in which it has been delivered. I would vote up your answer but I'm shy on reputation to do so :(. I accepted @Superbogly's answer because it 'feels' 'more d3' by ignoring the need for the forEach method - sounds terrible, doesn't it, blame the Python crowd for the term 'Pythonic', anyway - I'm new both to coding and StackOverflow so I just want to convey my appreciation for your response. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. His answer is indeed better than mine. I learnt a new thing by reading it.